# swift println float using string

Tags: string, swift, println

I wish to ask a conceptual question. My code is to print an array of float values of 5 decimal places onto the console. Why must it be String instead of Float? Ans[y] is an array of type float.

```
 println(String(format: "%.5f", Ans[y]))
```

Instead of Float

```
println(Float(format: "%.5f", Ans[y]))
```

Float gives an error of extra argument 'format' in call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of understanding what your words mean. String is an object type (a struct). Float is an object type (a struct). The syntax `Thing(...)` calls a Thing *initializer* - it creates a new object of type Thing and calls an initializer method `init(...)`. That's what you're doing when you say `String(...)` and `Float(...)`.

Well, there is a String `init(format:)` initializer (it actually comes from Foundation NSString, to which String is bridged), but there is no Float `init(format:)` initializer - the Float struct doesn't declare any such thing. So in the second code you're calling a non-existent method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use map() to format your Float array as string array. Btw you should give it a name starting with a lowercase letter. Try doing as follow:

```
let floatArray:[Float] = [1.23456,3.21098,2.78901]
let formattedArray = floatArray.map{String(format: "%.5f", $0)}
println(formattedArray)  // "[1.23456, 3.21098, 2.78901]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSLog instead of println. NSLog is still in the foundation class and has the flexibility of specifying the exact format you need.